# Is this simple cryptographic algorithm strong enough?

Tags: python, sockets, cryptography

Two computers communicate using sockets via Internet.
I just send the server program to another person and then my client program will send and receive strings.
I need the data to be cryptographed during the transmission.
My idea is to simply use a childish algorithm that doesn't need any key, but a pair of sequences containing all alphanumeric characters.

```
ROW1 = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'
```

The second row will contain the same characters but mixed up.  The original content will be translated to the second sequence before transmission and translated back after.

Now I'm wondering if this system could be safe.

Comment: not now you've told us your scheme...

Comment: No, it's not safe.  Use an established mechanism for secure communication.

Comment: Strong enough for what? Not that it's strong enough for anything at all ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have described is a simple [substitution cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_cipher). These sorts of ciphers were used in ancient Rome. A trivial frequency analysis of a few dozen letters of the ciphertext allows full key recovery, rendering the encryption as good as plain text, until the key (substitution alphabet) is changed.

In your case, other simple attacks such as replay attacks may also be relevant. An adversary could replay a previously eavesdropped command and the recipient would consider it fully valid, even though the adversary knows nothing about the key. Note that this attack would be possible even if you used a proper cipher like AES in a naive fashion – it serves to demonstrate how important the security of the whole protocol is.

There is a reason why proper cryptographic standards and protocols are so complex. Fortunately for us, we don't have to reinvent or reimplement them ourselves. A good choice in this case may be [TLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security). There are libraries available for almost every platform.

Also worth checking out: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/09/27/keep-it-secret-keep-it-safe.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Don't ever do this. You must use a standard approach; which will be tried and tested and well-researched.

Read these as a starting point

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Socket_Layer

Answer (score 4):

Safe from a mentally-challenged monkey perhaps but the NSA (or even a slightly adept cryptanalyst fresh out of High School) will have that decoded in very short time.

All you need to crack this would be a rudimentary knowledge of English letter frequency (or whatever target language you want to do analsis for) and a few cipher texts. In fact, it ranks right up there with ROT13 and Pig Latin in terms of unsuitability for encryption.

Comment: What if our conversation is in italian?

Comment: @donkeydown; you're not serious? How about for (language: languages){language.invokeNearlyMentallyChallengedMonkey()}

Comment: How could the cracker know about the kind of content?

Comment: @donkeydown: Italian also has character and char-group frequency, just like English. Cryptanalysis is not limited to English, and any crypto guy worth the money will attack from multiple angles (including a large number of languages).

Answer (score 2):

This type of approach is usually a bad idea. In fact I don't think is strong enough to use it for any purpose. I would suggest to take a look to well known algorithms. As you mentioned that you are working with sockets, I practical approach will be to create an SSL tunnel between both endpoints. As you did not give any information about the specific language I cannot point you to any references in particular.

Comment: I use Python. Is it easy (and free) to create that SSL tunnel?

Comment: Yes, take a look to http://docs.python.org/2/library/ssl.html

Comment: Actually, the kind of data I will transmit, is... quite dangerous: I will send system commands. And I guess I need a VERY safe algorithm -- for the sake of the other person's computer...

Comment: In that case, I will opt for certificate-based authentication over SSL.

Comment: @DanielH. TLS/SSL does use certificate authentication.

Comment: As far as I understand, the server should be on my computer, and the client will require a certificate, that I will provide; the certificate has to be created using openssl (a self-signed certificate) and must contain my ip address as the "Common name" parameter; the client will use ssl.match_hostname() to verify.

Comment: @ntoskrnl As far as I know, TLS/SSL (http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5246) by itself could be used without certificates. You just negotiate a key, but I agree that usually a certificate is involved. In this case, (@donkeydown) I will use both server and client certificates.